# Programme to print mulitples of 5 in a range specified by user

Tags: python

Im new to python and im trying to write a code which determine all the multiples of 5 in a range specified by the user. Im getting the code to go up in units of 5. eg if the range was 6 and 21, it would say that the multiples are 6,11,16,21.

```
a = int(input("Enter a value of a : "))
b = int(input("Enter a vlue of b : "))

if a%5 ==0:
    a = a+5

multiples = []

for value in range(a, b+1,5):
    multiples.append(value)

print(multiples)
```

I'm expected just multiples of 5 to be printed.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `[x for x in range(a, b + 1) if x % 5 == 0]`.

Comment: so if i set a to be 6 and b to be 21, my output is 6, 11, 16, 21.

Comment: Where do you think you are insuring that `a` is a multiple of 5?

Comment: Just to clarify, your expected output from the range 6 to 21 should be [10, 15, 20]?

Comment: @UdonN00dle yes thats the expected output

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your expected output from the range 6 to 21 is `[10, 15, 20]`, you can first test if the starting point is a multiple of 5 as you did with `if a % 5 == 0`, and if it is true, we can add 5 repeatedly until we hit the end of range, while appending all the steps into the output list.

However if `a % 5 == 0` gives you false, then we need to find the value to add to this starting point so that we can get the first multiple of 5 in this range, i.e.

```
diff = 5 - a % 5
```

and add this value to the starting point `a`, we get the first value:

```
first = a + diff
```

Then we can add 5 repeatedly until we hit the end of range.

### To put all the above into code:

```
# get user input for the range a to b
a = int(input("Enter a value of a : "))
b = int(input("Enter a value of b : "))

output_list = []

# determine first value
if a % 5 == 0: 
    first_val = a
else: 
    first_val = a + (5 - (a % 5))

# go through the range between the first value and the end, with step=5
for val in range(first_val, b + 1, 5):
    # append value to the list
    output_list.append(val)

print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to your `if` statement:

```
else:            # if it isn't a multiple of 5
    a += (5-a%5) # add enough to get to the next multiple of 5
```

Comment: Thank you, i think that was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find the reminder of input1 and then start looping with that reminder

```
    a = int(input("Enter a value of a : "))

    b = int(input("Enter a vlue of b : "))

    c=a%5 #reminder

    multiples = []

    for value in range(a+5-c, b+1,5):
       multiples.append(value)

    print(multiples)
```